# Как вернуть запись из текстового столбца как массив

Tags: php, laravel

В бд есть поле типа `longtext`, в него записан массив такого типа

```
[[[73.159332,49.912499],[73.161736,49.91781],[73.166199,49.912278],[73.159332,49.912499]]]
```

Вопрос в том, как мне получить этот массив не в текстовом виде, а в виде массива
Вот так:

```
"geometry": {
      "id": 7,
      "coordinates": [[[73.159332,49.912499],[73.161736,49.91781],[73.166199,49.912278],[73.159332,49.912499]]],
      "id_zone": 1
    }
```

А не как сейчас:

```
"geometry": {
      "id": 7,
      "coordinates": "[[[73.159332,49.912499],[73.161736,49.91781],[73.166199,49.912278],[73.159332,49.912499]]]",
      "id_zone": 1
    }
```

Comment: попробуйте указать `(array) $вашаСтрока` перед записью в переменную

Comment: А какая у вас БД? Если постгрес, то он умеет в массивы. Главное тип данных в столбце исправить.

Comment: если субд и ларавель не справятся, `json_decode('[[[73.159332,49.912499],[73.161736,49.91781],[73.166199,49.912278],[73.159332,49.912499]]]', True)`

Comment: В laravel можно задать protected $casts = ['coordinates' => 'array']; Что на выходе позволит использовать как массив.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашу модель : **App\User.php** (или любую другую)

Необходимо дописать **преобразователь** - [eloquent-mutators](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent-mutators)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
  /**
    * Атрибуты, которые должны быть преобразованы к базовым типам.
    *
    * @var array
    */
  protected $casts = [
    'options' => 'array',
  ];
}
```

Из статьи на русском языке есть преобразователь **$casts**, который приведет ваш атрибут к нужному типу.

В вашем случае

```
protected $casts = [
  'coordinates' => 'array',
];
```